# Перевод they в единственном числе

Tags: перевод, местоимения, этикет

В свете последних [событий в сети StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) хотелось бы понять как переводить слово they, употребленное в единственном числе, и словосочетания с ним (they did и т.д.), встречающиеся в гендерно-нейтральном контексте. В случае известного пола привычный перевод "он/она сделал/сделала", как оказалось, может кого-то оскорбить, а "оно сделало" звучит ужасно. Что делать в случае неизвестного пола (контекст отсутствует или гендерная нейтральность выдержана на 100%) неясно совсем.

Comment: is it about site-specific usage of pronouns or general guidelines on using gender-neutral pronouns in Russian? I'm asking because if former, then this belongs in meta.

Comment: @Quassnoi this question and answers to it can be applied in general case, not only specific to StackExchange network. I mentioned it just to give a context why I am asking (without it the question can seem unclear).

Comment: "Оно сделало" звучит не просто ужасно: оно прямо оскорбительно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They - это они. Если вы хотите придерживаться тех же стандартов гендерной нейтральности, что приняты в некоторых сообществах пользователей (далеко, кстати, не во всех),  то можете преспокойно писать "они" вместо "он"/"она", ну например:

> Если какому-то пользователю надо связаться с со службой поддержки, то им легче будет это сделать через веб-сайт.

Тут будет то же самое противоречие между единственным числом и местоимением во множественном числе - но это ровно то же самое противоречие, которое возникает в английском. Некоторые живут с таким противоречием, некоторые стараются по возможности всё писать во множественном числе.

А ещё проблемы надо решать по мере поступления. Возможно, вы будете писать всё время "он/она" и никто не оскорбится. А всё будете писать и будете. А никто всё равно не оскорбится.

Comment: Если слово пользователь в мужском роде, то местоимение тоже должно быть в мужском роде, иначе это ошибка.

Comment: @Anixx это вопрос фактического словоупотребления - в английском they тоже не должно сочетаться с единственным числом. В целом грамматически это разумеется ошибка, тут не поспоришь.

Comment: Singular they имеет богатую историю употребления в прошлом, включая Чосера, Шекспира, Байрона и Библию. Местоимение "они"  не имеет таких прецедентов  употребления.

Comment: @AlexYu а не могли бы вы, если вам несложно, привести пример гендер-нейтрального they в работах Шекспира, Чосера или Байрона.

Comment: “And every one to rest themselves betake...”, к примеру. А еще they употребляется в безличных предложениях, а они тоже все гендерно-нейтральные

Comment: Russian sorta kinda has history of singular "they" too: *они хочут свою образованность показать и всегда говорят о непонятном*, however it apparently has different undertone than its English counterpart.

Comment: @shabunc Вообще, считается грубостью направлять на википедию, но: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Older_usage . Обратите внимание, что самые древние примеры еще с "thorn"-letter: "þer"

Comment: @AlexYu по приведённой вами ссылке указано что для достижения гендерной нейтральности это выражение стало пользоваться позже - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Trend_toward_gender-neutral_language

Comment: @shabunc "They with a singular antecedent goes back to the Middle English of the 14th century[21][22] (slightly younger than they with a plural antecedent, which was borrowed from Old Norse in the 13th century),[23] and has remained in common use for centuries in spite of its proscription by traditional grammarians beginning in the late 18th century.[24][25]"  - т.е. исторически singular they **slightly younger than**  plural they

Comment: @AlexYu singular they и gender-neutral это разные вещи - очень близкие, но разные, ну например - "они изволят откушать"    - это не отменяет того, что и статья интересная, и замечания дельные!

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm not a linguist so take my words with tonne of salt but all cases I remembered with "они" in context of single person has some kind of humourous nuance. Maybe it's  some kind of intentional misuse.

Comment: @AlexYu it was actually ironical usage of so called majestic plural - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we

Comment: @Quassnoi this is not singular they. The grammatic number is plural

Comment: @Anixx: "singular they" means that it refers to a single person, not a group. In English you don't say "After the user logs out, they *has an option to log in again", you say "they have".

Answer (score 13):

В русском языке род не всегда связан с полом. Род местоимения должен соответствовать роду соответствующего существительного. Если вы пишете "пользователь", то должны называть его "он", не зависимо от пола. А если пишете "персона", то должны называть её "она", хотя это может быть мужчина. То есть, ничего оскорбительного нет если местоимение не соответствует реальному полу.
Если вы хотите быть вообще гендерно-нейтральным, можете использовать слово среднего рода ("лицо"), например. Так делают и многие законы.

Answer (score 6):

Проблемы нет,  потому что в каждой конкретной ситуации можно предложить разные варианты. Хочу напомнить о том,  что в русском языке существуют «нейтральные существительные», такие как «человек, персона, лицо», иногда можно использовать безличные предложения и старый верный вариант «он или она».Переводить калькой «они» сейчас кажется, мягко говоря,странным.Возможно, это и войдет в практику в будущем.

Answer (score 4):

Можно, хотя бы в части случаев, использовать безличный пассив - "было сделано".

Если какому-то пользователю надо связаться с со службой поддержки, то *это* легче будет сделать через веб-сайт.

Answer (score 2):

> как переводить слово they, употребленное в единственном числе, и словосочетания с ним (they did и т.д.)

There is a common pattern in Russian language for case like this.

This pattern is used mostly in legal documents, but if StackExchange requires common texts to be legaly clean, then you can use legal way of writing.

How to use the pattern.

The ending of female gender is put in parenthesis, because in Russian language female words are usually longer, that male words.

For example,

> Если он(-а) совершил(-а) действие и/или проявил(-а) бездействие, тогда содеянное наказывается штрафом от 5 до 10 МРОТ.
>
> Пилот посадил(-а) самолет на кукурузное поле.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but it must be noted that forms "он(а)" are usually used in instructions/manuals - texts when not only gender but the personality is not known at the moment. OP ask question about SO conversation when gender could be unknown but personality is known.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Stack Exchange is concerned, the official guide on pronouns states:

> For now, while the intent of being inclusive and respectful of all gender identities applies to all our communities, the specific requirements around pronoun usage apply only to English language sites. As we determine best practices in other languages, we’ll work with those communities and update guidance for those languages.

As for the other places, I'm not familiar with any usage practices widely enough to serve as general guidelines.

Comment: It is strange to see this answer after I replied to your comment: my question is not specifically about StackExchange.

Comment: @sanyash: that's what the second part of my answer addresses.